# How to bind static affinity for *all* Linux processes at startup?

Tags: cpu-usage, task-scheduler, realtime, affinity

I have one single-threaded process on server that I'd like to statically bind to one CPU core and give it all available computing power all the time (it's real-time process that is heavily affected by insufficient resources). Unfortunately machine is heavily overloaded so CPU is sitting at 60% CPU or more on average and process usually gets suffocated. I already assigned real-time round-robin priority 99 but it's still far from perfect.

How can I distribute all other processes to remaining 7 CPU cores at startup and leave one core dedicated for this one process?
I'm talking about situation where all newly spawned processes are already bound to 7 cores from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the cpu that you want to dedicate for your realtime process, using the kernel boot parameter isolcpus:

```
Remove the specified CPUs, as defined by the cpu_number values, from the general kernel SMP balancing and scheduler algroithms. The only way to move a process onto or off an "isolated" CPU is via the CPU affinity syscalls
```

If you are using a distro with systemd, you could could use `CPUAffinity` in your service unit

Comment: Unfortunately my version of systemd doesn't support CPUAffinity parameter yet, i tried that before but i got message that "unknown paremeter CPUAffinity something something". It's pretty old kernel and systemd version (from time of kernel 3.x). But I'll try isolcpus and report results, thanks

Comment: isolcpus works exactly as I expected, thenks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this so it's just a suggestion.

It seems that the `taskset` configuration is inherited. So you could as early as possible in the boot process make such a setting for PID 1 so that everything SystemD starts after that would use just those cores:

```
taskset -p 0x7F 1
```

Or you don't care at what point in the boot process this happens and just iterate over all existing processes.

Don't forget to change the setting for your special application...